# when entering my private key in MEW I change the public address to one that does not have the tokens of zilliqa

Tags: transactions

someone could help me send ZILL tokens to a wallet that does not accept them (from zilliqa) by mistake they are in the contract but when wanting to open that address with the private key in MEW I change the public key to a different one where no Are the tokens something can be done?

Comment: If the tokens were transfered to a contract then only the contract can transfer tokens. If the contract has no function defined to transfer tokens then the tokens are stuck in the contract and cannot be moved.

Comment: are the tokens in that contract but I can not move them because the wallet that contains them does not show them and when I try to open them with MEW it does not show them because I change the public key...

Comment: MEW has an option to add a custom token, if you have the address you should be able to add it. But if MEW already have it and it shows 0 tokens then you likely have 0 tokens, you can check your address in etherscan to verify if you havee tokens there. If the tokens show in etherscan you can file a bug with MEW so they can fix it. Another possibility is that you have other token with similar symbol and you have them mixed up.

Comment: First of all thank you for helping me look this is the address of the contract 0xfd76d4aeb6c125fc3fb29f71e65cd39e076501bdc112e5e587ee469ff803ab4f which says that the address 0x058b9f19ba92586a0837493d0c1dbc34f4bb8a8f has the tokens that address above is mine I have the private key but in the page zill the tokens do not appear and when opening in MEW with the private key of that same address opens a different address to the one above which does not have the tokens

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct private key? A private key should always generate the same address. Perhaps you can recover if you saved it to json wallet file. Or try with an old version of MEW site if they changed something. Unfortunately there's nothing you can do unless you have the private key that generates the `0x058b9f..`.

Comment: if I have the correct private key is the same I do not know why mew changes it and I also have the json file although when I try to open the json file in mew and metamask it marks me error in the 2 when opening with json I think everything will be fixed what it is not because it does not open it is probably a different chain of blocks no idea the vdd I have more than a month looking for solution and zilliqa nomas wash their hands

Comment: You didn't mention previously but you might want to try in a browser without Metamask installed so you are sure it didn't try to use Metamask account.